# Exporting a Google Sheet to a PDF: getDataAsString() returns an empty PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps

I have a single sheet spreadsheet with some data in the first few rows and columns. My end goal is to take snapshots of specific sheets and export them to PDFs.  The following function correctly exports a PDF, but the call to getDataAsString() returns an empty PDF.

```
function export() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE);
  var exportFile= DriveApp.getFileById(PDF_EXPORT_FILE);
  var pdfContent =   spreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getDataAsString();
  exportFile.setContent(pdfContent);
}
```

What do I need to do to create a PDF in a similar way to how the `Print` item in the `File` menu works?

Comment: Is it important for your purpose to set the content of the spreadsheet to an already existing pdf file, or would you be happy with exporting it to a new pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

To Overwrite pdf while retaining URL, you may use `Drive.Files.update()`:

```
function export() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE);
  var exportFile= DriveApp.getFileById(PDF_EXPORT_FILE);
  var pdfContent =   spreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  Drive.Files.update({
    title: exportFile.getName(), mimeType: exportFile.getMimeType()
  }, exportFile.getId(), pdfContent);
}
```

or if you just want to *create a new pdf and save it to a folder*:

```
function export() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE);
  var exportFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(EXPORT_FOLDER_ID);
  var pdfContent = spreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName("new-name");
  exportFolder.createFile(pdfContent);
}
```

> Note: if you get `“Drive” is not defined` error, please enable **Drive Api** *(Resources -> Advanced Google Services -> Enable Drive Api)*